# How to load corresponding data in a given Search

Tags: java, arrays, string, search, java-io

I already make a program that save the entered data in the textfields. It's saving technique is like this

```
data0 = student number
data1 = name
data2 = section
data3 = cp
data4 = email
data5 = address
```

inside the saved file:

```
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
```

data0 has is unique,
this is the code I use to search Student No. "data0"
if I search 12293 for example

```
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
12293 | blahh | blehh | blihh | blohh | bluhh
data0 | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | data5
```

and there's a match in line 3, blah,blehh,blihh,blohh,bluhh must be printed in different textarea

but I don't know how to slice data1|data2|data3|data4|data5| into a array when a search has a match

this my code:

```
import java.io.*;

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Jfetizanan
 */
public class DATALOAD {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     * @throws FileNotFoundException
     * @throws IOException  
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        try{
      FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("data.dat");
            try (DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream)) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

                 if (strLine.startsWith("JFETZ")){
                 System.out.println("Data Found");

                 }
                 else
                 {System.out.println("Nothing Found in this line");}
                }
            }
      }catch (Exception e){
          System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream if you want to read text, its more confusing than useful.

Answer (score 0):

[`split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it by `|` do

```
String values[] = strLine.split("\\|");
```

and compare the search key with first element of array `values[0]`

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
 String values[] = strLine.split("\\|");
 if ("JFETZ".equals(values[0]))){
   System.out.println("Data Found");
 }else{
   System.out.println("Nothing Found in this line");}
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `str` like :

```
String str = "12293 | blahh | blehh | blihh | blohh | bluhh";
String[] arr = str.split("\\| "); // give space after | to trim spaces
```

Comment: yeah exactly, I just checked on Eclipse. Editing. :)